# Connection to Virtuoso Database with sparqlib PHP

Tags: virtuoso

I am using PHP to connect to endpoint to Virtuoso.

I have found SPARQL library and I have made some queries. The problem is that if I insert a huge string, Virtuoso doesn't allow me. When I do this query from Conductor, it is inserted. So I want to connect to database through sparqlib and insert my username and password. I haven't found anything like this. Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me… not least, what you mean by "Virtuoso doesn't allow [you] to insert a huge string." Do you get an error message? What is it? PHP connections to Virtuoso are often most easily done via ODBC, where you can use [SPASQL (SPARQL-in-SQL)](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/odbcimplementation.html#odbcimplementationext) when desired.

Comment: That said... [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/)-specific questions are often better raised to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [public OpenLink Support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or [confidential OpenLink Support cases](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of Virtuoso.